# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert class to same class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm doing a simple bit of code. I have a class Plugin that is meant to be extended, with a function initialise():

```
package me.bleachisback.cocmod {
    import me.bleachisback.cocmod.CoCMain;

    public class Plugin {
        private var _main:CoCMain;
        private var _name:String;
        private var _desc:String;
        private var _ver:String;
        private var _auth:String;
        internal var _enabled:Boolean = false;

        internal function initialise(main:CoCMain, name:String, description:String, version:String, author:String):void {
            _main = main;
            _name = name;
            _desc = description;
            _ver = version;
            _auth = author;
        }
    }
}
```

And my main class which loads the plugins, and then initialises them:

```
package me.bleachisback.cocmod {
    import me.bleachisback.cocmod.Plugin;

    public class CoCMain extends MovieClip {
        private function pluginLoadingComplete(e:Event):void {
            //This class extends Plugin
            var plugin:Object = new e.target.content.mainClass();
            var desc:XML = new XML(e.target.content.description);
            trace(this); //outputs: [object CoCMain]
            plugin.initialise(this, desc.name[0], desc.description[0], desc.version[0], desc.author[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

But at the end, when I try to use the initialise function, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert me.bleachisback.cocmod::CoCMain@4dfc041 to me.bleachisback.cocmod.CoCMain.
    at me.bleachisback.cocmod::CoCMain/pluginLoadingComplete()
```

Implying I cannot convert a class to itself???

Comment: have you tried doing something along the lines of... `var plugin:e.target.content.mainClass() = new e.target.content.mainClass();` or setting a class variable... `var newClass:Class = e.target.content.mainClass();` and then `var plugin:newClass = new newClass();`

Comment: Yes, that is what I did at first, and then it gave me this error: `1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: newClass`. I have also tried `var plugin:Plugin = new e.target.content.mainClass();` but then it just gives me this error: `Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert plugin.bleachisback.testPlugin::TestMain@afc6309 to me.bleachisback.cocmod.Plugin` even though TestMain does extend Plugin.

Comment: in your initializing function, try initializing `_main` and then setting it equal to `main`, i.e. `_main = new CoCMain();` and then `_main = main`. The error is saying that your trying to convert the object `CoCMain@4dfc041`, which is a `CoCMain Object` at memory location `4dfc041`, to a `Class`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The code never even gets to that point, because the error occurs in CoCMain/pluginLoadingComplete(), and not Plugin/initialise().

Comment: This usually happeing when you have the same class compiled by different SWF's - are you loading SWF with the `CoCMain` to another SWF? - You may try to exclude this class from this SWF (not so easy when Flash and fla is used).

Comment: Well, the .swf that I am loading uses a .swc file of my main .swf as a library so that it can extend Plugin. Would that cause it? And if so, how would I go about fixing it but also being able to extend Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

when you load an external SWF, you can specify the applicationDomain in which class definitions will be loaded. by default, an external loaded SWF will place its class definition in a new application domain, so classes named equally won't be replaced in the original application domain.

Try to load the SWF into the current application domain, like this:

```
var ldrContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
```

Note the **ApplicationDomain.currentDomain** when creating the LoaderContext.

You can check an example here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html

Comment: I tried that, but when I put `trace(e.target.applicationDomain == ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);` in pluginLoadingComplete(), it outputs as false, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you passing the loaderContext to the load method of the loader you are using? Like this:
`ldr.load(req, ldrContext);`

Comment: `loader.load(url, new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));` is what I am using.

Comment: Is the loaded SWF In a different domain from the main application?

Comment: You can try too:

`var plugin:Plugin = new ( e.target.applicationDomain.getDefinitionByName("me.bleachisback.cocmod.Plugin") as Class)() as Plugin;`

and see what happens